# Check if there are any SoundCloud players playing

Tags: api, widget, soundcloud

I need to find out if it is possible to check if there are any sound cloud players playing (or if there are none playing) on a page at any given point.
The sound cloud api seems to allow you to check if a player is paused but i'm not sure if this apply's to all players on a page or not?
Any thoughts or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on this but looking at [the embedded widget page](https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed), they are using an iFrame, meaning it's running in an isolated environment. Unless they go out of their way to provide this feature (using cross-document messaging for example), it won't be possible.

(Well, if you want to go for a really weird hack, you could request the user's microphone permissions and detect the audio playing :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a separate SC.widget object for each player on the page. You could create a script to find them if all the iframes on the page are soundcloud players like this:

```
var widgets=new Array();
$('iframe').each(function (index, iframe) {
    widgets.push(SC.Widget(iframe));
});
```

Then you could check if all of them are paused.